# SQL Server taking time to execute query but the CPU, Read, Write are low

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server, query execution is taking a lot of time, but the CPU read and write are not taking time. Is there a way to find out where the time is being spent?

Also when we run the same query on the database during the same time it executes very fast.

[image]

Comment: Locking. Resource you are reading from may be used by other query.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda thanks makes sense but how do I identify which other query is competing for the same resource. I do not seem to see any deadlocks

Comment: sp_whoisactive - https://github.com/amachanic/sp_whoisactive

Comment: "Also when we run the same query on the database during the same time it executes very fast." - sounds like a parameter sniffing http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html